# Python: Luhn's algorithm / if statement never executes

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, if-statement, luhn

I am trying to implement the Luhn's algorithm to check for credit card number validity. To do this every second digit needs to be multiplied by 2 and if the result is >9 it then is replaced by the sum of the digits.

```
def luhn_check(creditcardnr):
"""
check if credit card number is valid using the Luhn's algorithm
"""

som = 0
for i, digit in enumerate([int(x) for x in str(creditcardnr)]):
    if i in range(1, len(str(creditcardnr))-1,2):
        digit *= 2
        if digit > 9:
            digit -= digitsum(digit)
    som += digit
    print('digit :',digit,'    sum :',som)

return som % 10 == 0
```

When I run this code I get as result

```
digit : 5    sum : 5
digit : 2    sum : 7
digit : 2    sum : 9
digit : 9    sum : 18
digit : 7    sum : 25
digit : 2    sum : 27
digit : 0    sum : 27
digit : 9    sum : 36
digit : 3    sum : 39
digit : 9    sum : 48
digit : 6    sum : 54
False
```

the second sum should be 9 not 7

digitsum() is a function that replaces an integer by the sum of it's digits

Comment: This page may help you, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm near the bottom is a Python example

Comment: You're printing the modified value of `digit`, not the actual digit (and also `digit -= digitsum(digit)` is wrong, and `if i in range(1, len(str(creditcardnr))-1,2)` is a verbose and buggy way to check whether `i` is odd).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work against `52297209396` - assuming:

```
def digitsum(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s
```

But neither does the [Wikipedia version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) - [per Simon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579117/python-luhns-algorithm-if-statement-never-executes#comment90123594_51579117):

```
def check_luhn(purported_cc):
    sum_ = 0
    parity = len(purported_cc) % 2
    for i, digit in enumerate([int(x) for x in purported_cc]):
        if i % 2 == parity:
            digit *= 2
            if digit > 9:
                digit -= 9
        sum_ += digit
    return sum_ % 10 == 0

print(luhn_check(52297209396))  # False
```

However, with `digitsum(n)` defined above, I cannot reproduce your error:

> the second sum should be 9 not 7

```
('digit :', 5, '    sum :', 5)
('digit :', 4, '    sum :', 9)
('digit :', 2, '    sum :', 11)
('digit :', 9, '    sum :', 20)
('digit :', 7, '    sum :', 27)
('digit :', 4, '    sum :', 31)
```

So I'm assuming `52297209396` is invalid.

The number `79927398713` (an example of a working number, via Wikipedia) does work against the Wikipedia statement of the algorithm (`check_luhn()` returns `True`, `luhn_check()` returns `False`) - so you could try using that instead.